# active server page error 'ASP 0131'

Tags: iis, asp-classic

I have an old ASP classic application that gives the following error when accessed by some browsers.

> Active Server Pages error 'ASP 0131'
>
> Disallowed Parent Path

We confirmed that the checkbox for accessing parent directories using ".." had been checked for this IIS site/application.  There is no problem accessing the pages on my desktop using Chrome; however on my laptop, using the same version of Chrome, I get the above message from the server.

From the same Windows 10 laptop, I can navigate the site fine using the Microsoft browser. Ultimately, I may have to edit the pages to get rid of the ".." in the application but would like a fix in the meantime.

Comment: Backup up a second, you are using both a Desktop and a Laptop, where is the Site running from the Desktop the Laptop or Both? *"I get the above message from the server"* which server?, the Desktop, the Laptop or something else?? If it's not working on the Laptop and the site runs locally on the Laptop then you need to make sure Parent Paths is enabled on that local site.

Comment: Can it be a cache in Chrome on laptop? It should not behave differently in Chrome/IE.

Comment: Let me just clarify what I'm saying. The `Enable Parent Paths` is a IIS configuration value so for it to effect one but not the other must mean they are two separate IIS instances. If you could explain how your environment is setup it might help. At the moment I think you are probably running your website using IIS express locally on each machine and wondering why they are different, but that is purely a guess.

Comment: @smirnov Don't think caching would cause this. OP also mentions that it behaves differently in Chrome on the different machines so it's not a browser specific thing either.

Comment: It's only your guess, and we need to wait for his reply. As of now, I see only one machine where it does not work - his laptop. I guess it could be due to a local/server cache (maybe it can be checked using random query string i.e. page.asp?12345). He also clearly mentioned that IIS is configured, so I believe it cannot be because of 2 different instances, or IIS Express.

Comment: @smirnov Point is **it's all a guess** because the OP hasn't provided enough information in the first place. Either way we'll see.

Comment: The actual IIS server is running on a remote rack server.  It is not IIS express and the application has been running for years.  The only change is that the physical machine was moved to a different location. I am just using the desktop and laptop to access the ASP application.  That is why I am so baffled since the laptop and desktop are both accessing the same server.  The problem was replicated by another person accessing the site using yet another machine.  I will have to contact the person babysitting the server to find out which version of IIS is running.